# MS SQL Server Actual CPU Cost per physical operation

Tags: sql-server, performance, cpu-usage, sql-execution-plan

I have query executing slowly on Microsoft SQL Server. Here are the query and execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJUrHRwng

The query is extremely slow:

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 30, logical reads 184041, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'SiteVersions'. Scan count 1, logical reads 363, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 351, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#BB50937F'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5979, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'AllWebs'. Scan count 11, logical reads 3041, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'AllSites'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 715296 ms,  elapsed time = 873728 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

This is on a dual Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 0 @ 2.70GHz, 2700 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 16 Logical Processor(s) system. The query executes with a max-dop of 1.

The actual execution plan indicates that a specific sort operation has the largest estimated cost and that there are no operations that return an extremely large number of rows.

However, when I examine the actual execution plan, I find it very unlikely that the sort operation causes all the CPU load. E.g., when I execute the sort operation in a separate stand-alone query, it is very fast.

I suspect the merge join of being the performance killer instead: it joins two averagely large rowsets (29840 and 9557 rows, resp.), resulting in potentially a very large number of joined rows. It has a not very restrictive WHERE clause and an expensive RESIDUAL operation with several functions that need to be evaluated for each residual row. However, I can't support my suspicion with actual numbers.

Therefore, I have a few questions so I can validate my suspicion:

- Is there a way to get the actual CPU cost reported per physical operation from SQL Server?
- Is there a way to report on the actual number of RESIDUAL operations executed and/or the number of rows that remain after the WHERE clause in the Merge Join operation?
- Is there a way to estimate the CPU cost associated with the 184041 reported Logical Reads on 'Worktable'?
- Is there a way to find out which physical operation uses the 'Worktable'

Regards, Beat

Comment: [This link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) might help you to share the execution plan.

Comment: Try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. You appear to have a table variable in there that the optimizer faithfully assumes to have only 1 row (as it doesn't maintain statistics for table variables). It actually has 30 000 rows, which skews overall row estimates considerably. `RECOMPILE` fixes that, at least (this isn't documented, but it does). So would using a temp table instead.

Comment: Thanks for the link @DavidG, I edited the question and used the link to improve the sharing of the execution plan.

Comment: I would also consider adding covering index on SiteId, WebId, VersionId, Id get rid of clustered index scan and sorting - those 2 operations occupy the most of execution time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Jeroen Mostert. I just tried it by executing the query with `option (RECOMPILE)`. Unfortunately, it doesn't improve query performance: **CPU time = 723298 ms,  elapsed time = 871256 ms**. Also, the query plan hasn't changed substantially: [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkpk3APng). Furthermore, I don't fully understand your comment. What table variable are you referring to?

Comment: Whoops. I missed that you're using scalar UDFs in your query as well. [Just say no to those](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2012/05/20/t-sql-user-defined-functions-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-part-1.aspx). There's literally no query that won't run faster if you refactor scalar UDFs into inline table-valued UDFs (though the gains aren't always substantial, obviously -- but they're never zero). For starters, thanks to those functions your query is using only one thread, since scalar UDFs inhibit parallelism. (Although you apparently want that given `MAXDOP`...)

Comment: @BeatNideröst: `@SiteSequenceVersions` is a table-valued parameter.

Comment: @Rafal Ziolkowski, what makes you conclude that the clustered index scan en sorting operations occupy most of the execution time?

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert Thanks for your tip regarding UDFs. I'll pass your suggestion to Microsoft as it is SharePoint that is generating this query! ;-)

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert Regarding `@SiteSequenceVersions` - I see what you mean. The table is declared in a statement just before the `SELECT` query and there are 10 rows in the table. The reported **Actual Number of Rows** is 29840 because the table is scanned 2984 times because of the Nested Loop (Inner Join) directly above it.

Comment: When you look at query plan those 2 ops take most of query cost. You want to get those values as low as possible. Most likely your Worktable from IO stats is just for purpose of sort. If you can eliminate need for sorting and scanning - it might help. However I agree with @JeroenMostert - UDF might be the ultimate killer here.

Comment: @Rafal Ziolkowski - I can't conclude that from the query plan. I see that those operations have a high Estimated Cost but these are only estimations, not the actual values and I believe the estimations are way off.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry too much about the CPU costs you are seeing, they are merely an indicator and can give an idea about how much pressure your CPU is getting from the query. In this case I think the CPU cost is caused by the complexity of the query, with the rank() in the subquery and the functions in the where clause.

I would try and split up your query in a few logical parts, in order to help the query optimizer figure out an optimal plan and improve it's work with the intermediate results:

```
    select  SiteId
          , WebId
          , VersionId
          , Version
          , rank() over (partition by SiteId, WebId, VersionId order by Id desc) as Rank
    into    #tempSiteVersions
    from    SiteVersions;

    with cteFirstRankingSites as
    (
        select  SV.SiteId
              , S.PlatformVersion
              , SV.Version
              , SSV.ApplicableWebTemplate
              , W.WebTemplate
              , SSV.PreviousTargetVersionNumber
              , SSV.TargetVersionNumber
        from    #tempSiteVersions as SV
                join TVF_Webs_NoLock_ALL() as W on W.SiteId = SV.SiteId
                join Sites as S with (nolock) on W.SiteId = S.Id
                join @SiteSequenceVersions as SSV on SV.VersionId = SSV.Id
        where   SV.Rank = 1
    )
    select distinct
            SiteId
    from    [cteFirstRankingSites] as frs
    where   (
             (
              (dbo.fn_ConvertVersionToNumber(frs.PlatformVersion) < 15000000000000)
              and (dbo.fn_ConvertVersionToNumber(frs.Version) < frs.PreviousTargetVersionNumber)
             )
             or (
                 (dbo.fn_ConvertVersionToNumber(frs.PlatformVersion) >= 15000000000000)
                 and (dbo.fn_ConvertVersionToNumber(frs.Version) < frs.TargetVersionNumber)
                )
            )
            and (
                 frs.ApplicableWebTemplate = 0
                 or frs.ApplicableWebTemplate = frs.WebTemplate
                )
```

There might be a syntax error in there as I don't have the actual tables and functions to work with, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your suggestion (the syntax was 100% correct!). Unfortunately, the performance is still extremely bad. Also, I can't edit the query in the actual workload as this is an automatically generated query by Microsoft SharePoint. And furthermore, my question was not how to optimize the query but how to determine the actual CPU cost associated with the physical Merge Join operation. Do you have an answer to that question?

Comment: I can't help you with the actual CPU cost for in individual operation, maybe someone else has a way to determine this. As far as I know the estimated cost is used by the optimizer to determine the most efficient plan to use. Hence why I suggested changing the query.

Comment: Also, the merge operator doesn't seem to be the issue, you are sorting the entire table with the RANK() function, with is causing a clustered index (table) scan and a sorting operation with high overall cost. Those two operations in the query plan, take up 84% of the total execution. Limit the data that needs to be ranked first, than apply the rank() as that will call the sorting operation.

Comment: Again, if it's possible to do within the Sharepoint environment, I don't have any experience with that.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why you think the clustered index scan and the sorting operation take up 84% of the **actual** cost? I can see that the cost **estimates** indicate that these operations are the culprit, but I believe these **estimates** are wrong. Hence my question if there is a way to retrieve the **actual** CPU cost!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the actual CPU cost reported per physical operation from SQL Server?

you can use Set Statistics profile on like below,it reports each logical operator seperately or else you can right click the logical operator to see cost

**Option 1:**

Set statistics profile on
your query

**Option 2:**
Right click and see the node properties
[image]

**Option 3:**
Applicable from 2016 sp1,you can use below DMV ,but you have to append `set statistics profile` before your query

This way you can track live statistics and lot more info

```
select 
session_id,physical_operator_name,
row_count,actual_read_row_count,estimate_row_count,estimated_read_row_count,
rebind_count,
rewind_count,
scan_count,
logical_read_count,
physical_read_count,
logical_read_count
 from
sys.dm_exec_query_profiles
where session_id=55;
```

> Is there a way to report on the actual number of RESIDUAL operations executed and/or the number of rows that remain after the WHERE clause in the Merge Join operation?

This has been implemented in SQLServer,but for this to appear ,you have to be on SSMS 2016 and a version greater than SQL2012 sp3,(i am on 2016 sp1,i can see,not sure for 2014)  .See below screenshot from my machine  ..

[image]

> Is there a way to estimate the CPU cost associated with the 184041 reported Logical Reads on 'Worktable'?

Worktable will be associated with an operator,so tracking the operator will give you the cost of the operator

> Is there a way to find out which physical operation uses the 'Worktable'

Mostly Sort operators use work table .In your case,it is the operator with sort warning

**Few recommendations  on fixing the query :**

1.) I see sort operator  in Partition by query has 73% cost,so i recommend using below index to eliminate sort .**This index will be applicable only for this query**

```
create index nci_somename on siteversions
(siteid,webid,versionid,id desc)
include(version)
```

Also i recommend inserting the above output into a derived table ,if the table is huge,so that SQL can have right statistics

2.)The All webs column shows stats warning,try updating statistics on that table or creating one manually

3.)Your predicates are like below

```
dbo.fn_ConvertVersionToNumber(S.PlatformVersion) < 15000000000000)
```

those type of predicates won't be sargable at all.try rewriting them

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate reply. Regarding the options you supply for returning the actual CPU costs, as far as I can tell these only return actual Rows and execution times, not the actual CPU costs. And the CPU costs that are reported are only the estimates that were used by the query optimizer before the query was actually executed. Or am I misunderstanding the meaning of the reported values? Thanks for the tip regarding the `Worktable`.

Comment: I **think**,even those values say estimated cpu cost,those may be the nearest ones you can get

Comment: The estimates are the only values I was able to find, hence my original question. So you might be right. In that case, there is no straight forward way to determine if the CPU load is caused by (the repetitive invocations of) the functions (which the query optimizer undoubtedly wrongly estimates to have 0 CPU cost!).

Comment: what about changing the index i suggested and tuning based on high cost operators

Comment: As this is a Microsoft SharePoint content database, I can't go around adding indices like that. Also, I don't think the high cost estimates of the query optimizer are correct.